# Using Camera in Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, camera

I have been trying to implement the camera into my application following this [tutorial](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/). The source code for the example works fine, but when I try to use it in my own application I get an error for

```
_button.setOnclickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());
```

The error is

> ButtonClickHandler cannot be resolved to a type

I can't figure out what the matter is at all, if anybody has an idea I'd appreciate some help !!

Comment: Have you implemented the inline class ButtonClickHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create the ButtonClickHandler class in your project like on this website ?

```
public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener
{
public void onClick( View view ){
    startCameraActivity();
}
}
```

Comment: Think that was it alright, too much fiddeling is after making my R file commit sucide now :(